# Merge 3 IEnumerable<Application> lists into one

Tags: c#, linq, merge, ienumerable

I have simplified my problem

```
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

My 3 lists:

```
IEnumerable<Application> applications1 = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 1, Status = 1},
    new Application {Id = 2, Version = 1, Status = 1},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 3, Status = 1}
};

IEnumerable<Application> applications2 = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 2, Status = 2},
    new Application {Id = 2, Version = 2, Status = 2},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 1, Status = 0}
};

IEnumerable<Application> applications3 = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 5, Status = 1},
    new Application {Id = 2, Version = 0, Status = 1},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 6, Status = 1}
};
```

I want to produce this:

```
IEnumerable<Application> applications4 = new List<Application>
{
    new Application {Id = 1, Version = 5, Status = 2},
    new Application {Id = 2, Version = 2, Status = 2},
    new Application {Id = 3, Version = 6, Status = 1}
};
```

I.e. one list with **the highest value of Version and Status**.
I have tried with LINQ but I don't get it.

My best is this, but it just gets the highest version. I don't understand how I do when there are 2 properties to select from:

```
IEnumerable<Application> applications4 = applications1
    .Concat(applications2)
    .Concat(applications3)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate((acc, curr) => acc.Version > curr.Version ? acc: curr ))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: If you can't achieve your goal with linq now, it's best to just write out the code with for-loops. It is of little use to write a very difficult linq query. You should also be able to read it again later. It's also not that linq is faster than writing out the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `Max()` to get the max values from the grouped properties.

```cs
IEnumerable<Application> applications4 = applications1
    .Concat(applications2)
    .Concat(applications3)
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    .Select(g => new Application
            {
                Id = g.Key,
                Version = g.Max(x => x.Version),
                Status = g.Max(x => x.Status)
            })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RX35PB)

Comment: Hi, ya first I have the first thought as you. But when read in detail, **one list with the highest version of Version and Status** and the sample data `new Application {Id = 1, Version = 5, Status = 2}`. That's why the `Max` is needed. =)

Comment: @Prasad Telkikar, main here is "idea" (concept). Proper implemenation remains on OP. There is no problem to remove `Max` for `Status`, but if you look again to OP's "desired output" you'll see that `Status` also is highest value from group of same `Id`'s

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar from the example it seems op wants the highest value for both, regardless if they appear in the same record or not

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar Sorry for being unclear. I want the highest value for both.

Comment: @Auditive, You guys are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your question misses a quite important point - which property (Version or Status) is more important?

I made an assumption that version is more important, and created a custom comparer to sort the results. Basically what I would want is to *group* the items by application id, and then get the highest result. I used a custom comparer to get it. If you don't want to use the comparer, you can always change it to:
.Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).ThenBy(x => x.Status).First());

```
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IEnumerable<Application> applications1 = new List<Application>
            {
                new Application {Id = 1, Version = 1, Status = 1},
                new Application {Id = 2, Version = 1, Status = 1},
                new Application {Id = 3, Version = 3, Status = 1}
            };

            IEnumerable<Application> applications2 = new List<Application>
            {
                new Application {Id = 1, Version = 2, Status = 2},
                new Application {Id = 2, Version = 2, Status = 2},
                new Application {Id = 3, Version = 1, Status = 0}
            };

            IEnumerable<Application> applications3 = new List<Application>
            {
                new Application {Id = 1, Version = 5, Status = 1},
                new Application {Id = 2, Version = 0, Status = 1},
                new Application {Id = 3, Version = 6, Status = 1}
            };

// you can use OrderByDescending().First() for applications using EF lower than 6.0.0
            var applications4 = applications1.Union(applications2).Union(applications3)
                .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                .Select(x => x.MaxBy(x => x, new VersionStatusComparer()));

            foreach (var item in applications4)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} Version: {1} Status: {2}", item.Id, item.Version, item.Status);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class VersionStatusComparer : IComparer<Application>
    {
        public int Compare(Application? x, Application? y)
        {
            var versionResult = CompareVersion(x.Version, y.Version);
            if (versionResult == 0)
            {
                return CompareStatus(x.Status, y.Status);
            }

            return versionResult;
        }

        private int CompareVersion(int xVersion, int yVersion)
        {
            if (xVersion > yVersion)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (xVersion < yVersion)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        private int CompareStatus(int xStatus, int yStatus)
        {
            if (xStatus > yStatus)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (xStatus < yStatus)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach more oriented OOP but that seem more explicit I hope. You can update the `Merge` logic if you need a more complexe scenario.
It's with O(n) complexity (Array of n element would need n "steep" to complete) and use dictionary:

```cs
public class Application
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public bool Merge(Application app){
        if(app.Id != Id) return false;
        this.Version = Math.Max(app.Version, this.Version);
        this.Status = Math.Max(app.Status, this.Status);
        return true;
    }
}
//...
IEnumerable<Application> applications4 = new List<Application>();
Dictionary<int,Application> res = new Dictionary<int,Application>();
        
foreach( var app in applications1.Concat(applications2).Concat(applications3) ){
  // existing value, then update
  if( res.TryGetValue( app.Id, out Application appToProceed )) appToProceed.Merge(app);
  // new id value, then add
  else res.Add(app.Id,app);
}
//
applications4 = res.Values.ToList();
```

Regarding benchmark result, it's about ns, so just as pieces of information :

```
| Method                                        | Mean       | Error   | StdDev  | Gen0   | Allocated |
|---------------------------------------------- |-----------:|--------:|--------:|-------:|----------:|
| Benchmark_Using_Dictionary__3List_1000Element |   226.8 ns | 3.03 ns | 2.84 ns | 0.0780 |     408 B |
| Benchmark_Using_LINQ__3List_1000Element       |   299.7 ns | 4.04 ns | 3.59 ns | 0.1040 |     544 B |
| Benchmark_Using_Dictionary__3List_3Element    |   652.5 ns | 2.09 ns | 1.85 ns | 0.1125 |     592 B |
| Benchmark_Using_LINQ__3List_3Element          | 1,631.4 ns | 8.12 ns | 7.59 ns | 0.2842 |    1488 B |
```

(3List mean app1 + app2 + app3 and 1000Element mean each app have 1000 id to work on)